# Get class name and method parameters in the aspect

Tags: java, logging, aop, aspectj, ajdt

I am working on a project that is basically a lot of processes that run periodically. Each process is a different class that extends an abstract class `RunnableProcess` we created, which contains the abstract method `run` with the signature below:

```
public abstract void run(Map processContext) throws IOException;
```

To improve modularization on the project, I'm starting to use Aspect Oriented Programming (AOP) to intercept the `run` calls from every `RunnableProcess`. I am still learning AOP, and I have the following code until now:

```
import static org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger;

import org.slf4j.Logger;
import process.RunnableProcess;
import java.util.Map;

public aspect ProcessRunInterceptorProtocol {

    pointcut runProcess() : call(void RunnableProcess.run(Map));

    before(): runProcess() {
        logger = getLogger(getClass());
        logger.info("running process " + thisJoinPoint);
    }

    after(): runProcess() {
        logger = getLogger(getClass());
        logger.info("process run successfuly " + thisJoinPoint);
    }

    private Logger logger;
}
```

The problem I'm having is related to the logger (`org.slf4j.Logger`) initialization - I would like it to be linked with the process class (the one that extended `RunnableProcess`, and it is being intercepted by the aspect), which is not happening here (the `getClass()` retrieves the aspect class). How can I do that without changing the implementation of `RunnableProcess` and its childs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want the **target** object on which the method is executed. Try this:

```java
logger = getLogger(thisJoinPoint.getTarget().getClass());
```